# Search with a batch-file in txt and replace values

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file named config.txt
This is what is included in the file:

> ```
> FacotyReset = No 
> Size = 15    
> Line = 12    
> MarkValue = 22
> ```

I would like to search in the txt find the corresponding value … ex. of size that in this case is equal to 15 and change it to 20.

Comment: *sigh* [What](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=windows+batch+replace)... [have](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=batch+replace+line)... [you](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows%20batch%20replace%20text%20in%20file)... [tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
>config.txt.tmp ( <nul set /p "=" )
for /f "delims=" %%A in (config.txt) do (
    set "found=false"
    for /f "tokens=1,2,3,*" %%W in ("%%A") do (
        if "%%W"=="Size" (
            echo %%W %%X 20 %%Z>>config.txt.tmp
            set "found=true"
        )
    )
    if "!found!"=="false" echo %%A>>config.txt.tmp
)
rem del config.txt
rem ren config.txt.tmp config.txt
endlocal
```